# How can i find out the server specs in unix?

Tags: unix, shell

Tried to search but can't find anything. Is there an unix equivalent to right clicking / properties on My Computer to see things like memory, cpu speed etc ?

Comment: Saying 'Unix' is a bit too broad as there are many Unix based operating systems. The procedure will be different for Linux, Solaris, HPUX, AIX, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could try http://ezix.org/project/wiki/HardwareLiSter

Comment: Many current distributions have this packages (`lshw`) available for installation without needing to build from source.

Comment: Its a nice tool but you might want to mention that it is Linux specific.

Answer (score 3):

[`dmidecode`](http://www.nongnu.org/dmidecode/) should work on most *nix systems, although it takes some translating.  There's also `biosdecode` in the same package.

Comment: This is a great utility.  It's like opening the box and peeking inside without the down time.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, such information can be found in `/proc/meminfo` and `/proc/cpuinfo`. It will be different on different systems.

Answer (score 2):

On **Solaris** you would use commands such as

`prtdiag`

`prtconf`

`psrinfo -v`  (CPU speed)

Answer (score 1):

A couple more useful Linux commands:

- `lshw`
- `lsusb`

Answer (score 1):

There are many useful tools that can help you: dmidecode, lshw, lspci, lsusb, lscpu

Answer (score 1):

There are a few commands you might want to consider running, to see if they're available on your system: `lsusb`, `lshw`, `lspci`.

Be more specific -- what do you mean by Unix? Is this a Solaris box, HPUX machine, FreeBSD, RedHat Linux? That matters.

Answer (score 0):

some other commands, depending on distributions 
lspci, hwclock, biosdecode etc. Also, have a look at man -k hardware, man -k cpu , etc

Answer (score 0):

The following link has one code which get all the info for a server/system, but it works with RHEL/Fedora/Suse/Ubuntu. I havn't used it on any of the unix boxes so please try it out and let us know. Also what its output looks like on your system.

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2009/10/linux-system-info.html