# Can I find out the specs of a server/host machine through a VM?

Tags: linux, virtualhost, specifications

After looking at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/77920/how-can-i-find-out-the-server-specs-in-unix) I would like to know if those solutions will display the specs of the host machine (and not of the VM that is running)?

Does `cat /proc/meminfo`, `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, `lshw`, etc., show the VM specs, the host machine specs, or a combination of both (like host machine CPU and VM allocated memory)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat /proc/meminfo` will only show data from within your VM.

`cat /proc/cpuinfo` **generally** will show the real data from the host system, but depending on the virtualization methods used and the hosts's configuration, there's nothing stopping the hypervisor from modifying the data it presents to your VM.

Comment: Is there a way to see the host system stats through the VM?

Comment: Generally-speaking, no there isn't.

Comment: If you need that information, call your provider and ask them.